# ExpressJS rendering wrong static path during deeper url link on html5mode

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to achieve html5mode in my web application. I am using Angular's ui router to get there. The client side is working well. Whenever I opened the main webpage (127.1.1.1:8080) it loads perfectly. Clicking on a button that links to (127.1.1.1:8080/admin/dashboard) it loads perfectly too.

Refreshing 127.1.1.1:8080 is still fine.

The problem arouse when I refreshed the page of 127.1.1.1:8080/admin/dashboard.
It gives:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.1.1.1:8080/admin/libs/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css".
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.1.1.1:8080/admin/assets/css/style.css".
```

It seems that it is getting the css style wrongly. 
The path http://127.1.1.1:8080/admin/assets/css/style.css is a wrong path, it should be http://127.1.1.1:8080/assets/css/style.css instead. I believe I will have to rewrite the static path in my server.js and I have already done that. What have I missing still?

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    api = require('./app/routes'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 

app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/public/app'));
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets'));
app.use('/libs', express.static(__dirname + '/public/libs'));

app.post('/api/user', api.post);
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('/public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.listen('8080');
console.log('The magic happens on port 8080');
```

app.config.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider','$locationProvider'];

function config($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url:'/',
        templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state('admin', {
        url:'/admin',
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/admin.html',
        controller: 'AdminController',
        resolve: {app: check_logged}
    })
    .state('admin.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        template: 'I could sure use a drink right dashboad.'
    })
    .state('admin.product', {
        url: '/product',
        template: 'I could sure use a drink right product.'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true
    });
}
```

index.html

```
    <head>
    <meta  http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;" charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Comment: can please check doing this in index.html for css files - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/libs/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css">` and for other file as well.
`

Comment: the issue is related to wrong mime type served from server .. i guess

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css"> This works! @Chandan Thank you!

Comment: Please do write it as an answer for me to be able to accept it

Comment: Your guess is perfectly right.

Comment: Glad it helped. Wrote an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `type` attribute in CSS to `text/css` as follows -

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  ref="/libs/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css">
```

The issue is related with the mime-type.